# How to know AccountTeam in salesforce is enabled or disabled through any API with core java code?

Tags: java, rest, salesforce

**JAVA Code- I have coded the following code using rest API to connect with salesforce, following code is from the URL to get Schema or fields of AccountTeamMember(a standard object) object which  after establishing connection with salesforce org through RESTAPI**

```
            String schemaUrl = instanceurl + "/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/AccountTeamMember/describe";
            log.info("schemeaUrl " + schemaUrl);
            String responseString = "emptyschema";

          Header printHeader = new BasicHeader("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
            
            Header oAuthHeader = new BasicHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accesstoken);
            
            HttpGet schemaHttpGet = new HttpGet(schemaUrl);
            
            schemaHttpGet.addHeader(oAuthHeader);
            
            schemaHttpGet.addHeader(printHeader);
         
            int count = 0;

            response = httpClient.execute(schemaHttpGet);
            log.info("after executing HTTPGet : " + response);
            int iStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            log.info("iStatusCode : " + iStatusCode);
            if (iStatusCode == 200) {

      
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                log.warn("httpEntity : " + httpEntity);
                if (httpEntity != null) {

                    log.info("before responseString " + responseString);
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    log.info("after responseString " + responseString);
```

**** here after running this code i got all fields of AccountTeamMember(a standard object associated with account object) in Json format if I keep AccountTeams enable, through RestAPI I am able to get all fields as json object and if disable then 404 satus code

so here is My question Is there any other way to know AccountTeams is enabled for Account object other than this 404 status code and manually login to salesforce org? ****

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: I cannot upload the whole code due to restrictions i breifed into the summary about the objective

Comment: That's why I asked for a *minimal* but still complete example that shows the problem. You have much better chances to get a good answer if people can just copy & paste your code, run it, and see the problem. Then they can fix it, try again on their end, and finally post an answer.